# TensorFlow code reading: what does `sess.run()` do except evaluate?

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, debugging, machine-learning

I am reading the code of [influence function](https://github.com/kohpangwei/influence-release) (ICML 2017 best paper). There is a confusing [line](https://github.com/kohpangwei/influence-release/blob/master/influence/logisticRegressionWithLBFGS.py#L190) (190) which returns nothing `self.sess.run(self.set_params_op, feed_dict=params_feed_dict)`. Relevant snippets as follows:

```
params_feed_dict = {}
params_feed_dict[self.W_placeholder] = W
# params_feed_dict[self.b_placeholder] = b
self.sess.run(self.set_params_op, feed_dict=params_feed_dict)
if save_checkpoints: self.saver.save(self.sess, self.checkpoint_file, global_step=0)

if verbose:
    print('LBFGS training took %s iter.' % model.n_iter_)
    print('After training with LBFGS: ')
    self.print_model_eval()
```

The `self.set_params_op` is assigned by the following function, which is done in init function (whether I did it or not, it will be executed):

```
def set_params(self):
    self.W_placeholder = tf.placeholder(
        tf.float32,
        shape=[self.input_dim * self.num_classes],
        name='W_placeholder')

    set_weights = tf.assign(self.weights, self.W_placeholder, validate_shape=True)
    return [set_weights]
```

Then I tried to comment that line, but the print message of `self.print_model_eval()` changed.

The useful [snippets](https://github.com/kohpangwei/influence-release/blob/578bc458b4d7cc39ed7343b9b271a04b60c782b1/influence/genericNeuralNet.py#L305) about `print_model_eval()` defines as follows:

```
def print_model_eval():
    ...
    grad_loss_val, loss_no_reg_val, loss_val, train_acc_val = self.sess.run(
        [self.grad_total_loss_op, self.loss_no_reg, self.total_loss, self.accuracy_op],
        feed_dict=self.all_train_feed_dict)

    test_loss_val, test_acc_val = self.sess.run(
        [self.loss_no_reg, self.accuracy_op],
        feed_dict=self.all_test_feed_dict)
```

The tensors are obtained by:

```
self.total_loss, self.loss_no_reg, self.indiv_loss_no_reg = self.loss(
            self.logits, 
            self.labels_placeholder)
```

and

```
def loss(self, logits, labels):
    labels = tf.one_hot(labels, depth=self.num_classes)
    # correct_prob = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(labels, tf.nn.softmax(logits)), reduction_indices=1)
    cross_entropy = - tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(labels, tf.nn.log_softmax(logits)), reduction_indices=1)

    indiv_loss_no_reg = cross_entropy
    loss_no_reg = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy, name='xentropy_mean')
    tf.add_to_collection('losses', loss_no_reg)

    total_loss = tf.add_n(tf.get_collection('losses'), name='total_loss')

    return total_loss, loss_no_reg, indiv_loss_no_reg
```

My questions are:

1. How does `sess.run()` without return value affect the computation of other tensors?
2. What is the best practice to debug TensorFlow code?

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With TensorFlow in non-eager execution mode, first you create a graph with operations as the nodes. 
Then, within a session, you run the operations. Certain operations, like the initialisation of variables, don't return anything. They just assign values to the variables in the graph.

Here, `self.set_params_op` sounds like it could be an operation of this type. It may be setting values for some parameters. If you comment it out, my guess is that these parameters are not being set to the 'post training' values. So when you evaluate the model, you get different results.